# Comparing Matrix Elements pairwise without looping in Matlab

Tags: performance, loops, matlab, vectorization

I encountered the following Problem in Matlab:

I have a matrix  A, and I want to compare its elements pairwise to a large number of other matrices (B1, B2, B3, etc.) elements. Finally, I want to sum the larger elements, weighted by weights (w1, w2, w3, etc.).

I am trying to calculate the following sum:

S= w1 .* (max(A,B1)) + w2 .* (max(A,B2)) + w3 .* (max(A,B3)) ...  etc.

I wrote a loop over the index numbers of B and w, but this approach is very slow.

Is there a nice way to write a faster code for this problem, not using loops?

Thanks for your help

Comment: "I wrote a loop over the index numbers..." So are `w` and `B` actually 3-dimensional arrays, or do you have separate variables for `w1`, `w2`, etc.?

Comment: w is a vector containing w1, w2, etc., the B1, B2, B3 etc. are separate matrices

Comment: You wrote a loop over variable names `B1`, `B2`, etc.? The only way to do that is using `eval` and friends, which are (very strongly) not recommended to use. Code using `eval` is not only slow, but also hard to read and maintain. Instead, use a 3D array as the answer below, or a cell array such that you can index `B{1}`, `B{2}`, etc.  A loop using such a cell array will be quite fast. Looping is not what makes code slow in MATLAB (and hasn't been for a long time).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given:

```matlab
w = rand(1,10);
A = rand(5,5);
B1 = rand(5,5);
B2 = rand(5,5);
...
B10 = rand(5,5);
```

The first thing to do is to put all of the `B` matrices into a 3-dimensional array:

```
B = cat(3, B1, B2, ..., B10);
```

Since `max` is vectorized, the max between `A` and the individual `B`'s is:

```
S = max(A,B);
```

In order to apply the weights, we have to reshape them into the 3rd dimension to multiply the correct max:

```
w = reshape(w, 1, 1, 10);   % or permute(w, [1 3 2]);
S = w.*S;
```

Then to take the sum, we just tell `sum` to operate in the 3rd dimension:

```
S = sum(S, 3);
```

Comment: Note that `B` should be in a 3-dimensional array as early in the process as possible. Ideally you should be creating `B(:,:,1), B(:,:,2), ... B(:,:,n)` rather than `B1`, `B2`, ... `Bn`.